# Why is Subversion working so slow during the first run?

Tags: svn

I've recently run into a following problem. I am using Subversion 1.7 at home on my computer running Windows 7. I am working at home for a project via OpenVPN (but I don't think that's the issue).

Now, whenever I start my computer, I make the following operation in my project.

```
svn update .
```

In order to update. For the first time it runs unusually slow, for a minute it just thinks, even if there are no updates at all. Now, the following updates (and commits) run quite fast, they take about several seconds maximum. What is wrong with the first run? Some caching happens or what? IMHO, there is a caching process that is done during the first run after system reboot, which makes Subversion so slow. Is there a way to fix that, so that the cache would not flush after reboot?

P.S. At work I also use Subversion, but under ArchLinux. And I noticed there is also a delay during the first run after reboot, but not such significant, as for Windows. So, it seems like a OS-independent issue of Subversion. Does anyone know a fixaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> whenever I start my computer
>
> under ArchLinux. And I noticed there is also a delay during the first run after reboot

This is the key right here. On a cold boot, you're having to read **everything** from disk, which is many hundreds of times slower than reading from memory. On subsequent operations, the OS has cached most of the files needed in RAM, which will be a much faster operation.

Answer (score 0):

- Do you use a self-signed certificate on Subversion server? Make sure that the certificate is valid and you've accepted it on your machine.
- Verify that your do not experience connectivity issues accessing your DNS server,
- Verify that your and server machine have PTR (reverse lookup zone) record on DNS and that these records are correct,
- Verify that the DNS resolution works correctly from your machine machines.